# Iphone and Android networking

Tags: java, iphone, android, linux

I need to develop a server for online game that targets two platforms(for now) mentioned in the title. I've chosen java and linux as a programming platform. 

What frameworks are available for handling networking, I mean do I need to handle this from the low level and write my own communication protocol? 

The game is simple 2d game, no physics. Maybe you can suggest not a networking lib but a complete game engine?

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://maniacdev.com/2011/08/tutorial-build-a-multiplayer-cocos2d-game-that-runs-on-your-own-server/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3a%20maniacdev%20%28iPhone,%20iOS%204,%20iPad%20SDK%20Development%20Tutorial%20and%20Programming%20Tips%29) is a link fresh from hacker news. Hope it suits your need .